# How can i seperate only those rows in csv in which dates are present....for ex

Tags: python, csv

I/P:-

```
1) 2/14/16, 7:19 PM - +91 9823547956: Hi all...
2) 24/14/16, 5:15 PM - +91 8026549795: have a good day
3) You might remember an interesting scene from there..
4) Many of us might find that example too difficult
```

I need only rows which has dates as O/P:-

```
1) 2/14/16, 7:19 PM - +91 9823547956: Hi all...
2) 24/14/16, 5:15 PM - +91 8026549795: have a good day
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: this isn't a csv.

Comment: A CSV file should have the same fields in every line. It's a simple table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is regex,

```
import re
re.search(r'\d+/\d+/\d+','The date is 11/12/98')
```

To incorporate in code you can do:

```
import re
new_file  = open('/new/file.csv','w+')

for line in open('/path/to/csv'):
    if re.search(r'\d+/\d+/\d+',line):
        new_file.write(line)
```

Comment: you don't need the parentheses, since you don't extract the group. and you should close your files after using them.

Comment: Thanks, referred some other post for Regex. Copied stuff blindly, but tested.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Jean-François, your file is a simple text file, it is not a csv file. To achieve the output that you want, you can try with [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like below:

```
import re

with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
    with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.search('\d+\/\d+\/\d+', line):
                out.write(line)
```

Now, the content of `out.txt` is:

```
1) 2/14/16, 7:19 PM - +91 9823547956: Hi all...
2) 24/14/16, 5:15 PM - +91 8026549795: have a good day
```

When using [`with statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), you do not need to close your files explicitly (by calling `file.close()`), because it is done automatically by the end of the block.